# How to store each column of a .csv file into a variable with Bash

Tags: bash, variables, csv, awk, output

I try to store the content of a .csv file into variables with Bash. Everytime there's a coma I would like to create a new variable.

The .csv file looks like this :

2015-03-17,Soccer,15:00:00,15:30:00
2015-03-18,Basketball,21:00:00,22:00:00

I would like to store the date in a variable, the description (soccer...) into another variable, the hours each in a different variable. In the end I would have 4 variables.

I already tried :

```
for line in $(< filename)
do
    var1=$(cut -d , -f 1 filename)
    var2=$(cut -d , -f 2 filename)
    var3=$(cut -d , -f 3 filename)
    var4=$(cut -d , -f 4 filename)
done

echo "$var1"
```

But the ouput looks like this :

```
2015-03-17
2015-03-18
Soccer
Basketball
15:00:00
21:00:00
15:30:00
22:00:00
```

But I would like something like :

```
2015-03-17
Soccer
15:00:00
15:30:00
2015-03-18
Basketball
21:00:00
22:00:00
```

That would allow me to save the output of each column in a variable.

I also tried with awk

```
for line in 2
do
    awk -F "," '{print $1}' filename
    awk -F "," '{print $2}' filename
    awk -F "," '{print $3}' filename
    awk -F "," '{print $4}' filename
done
```

But I can't manage to show only the first line, and then the next one etc and store everything in a different variable.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it as below:

```
while IFS=, read -r date activity starttime endtime
do
  echo $activity
done < filename
```

If you set the **Internal Field Separator** variable `IFS` to be a comma, bash will interpret each comma separated expression as a new variable. You can then populate those variables within in the while loop whilst reading from the file

Answer (score 0):

In awk, of course you get the variables by default. You can do what you will with them, and then if you want to print them one per line, just set OFS to newline:

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS="\n" '{ print $1, $2, $3, $4 }' data.txt
2015-03-17
Soccer
15:00:00
15:30:00
2015-03-18
Basketball
21:00:00
22:00:00
```

If all you really want to do is convert the commas to newlines you can use this more idiomatic awk for that (or even just `tr ',' "\n" < data.txt`)

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS="\n" '{$1=$1}1' data.txt
2015-03-17
Soccer
15:00:00
15:30:00
2015-03-18
Basketball
21:00:00
22:00:00
```

`-F,` Set the input field separator to comma

`-v OFS="\n"` Set the output field separator to newline

`{$1=$1}` Reconsitute the line to use the output field separator

`1` Print the line